# Why arrow function can't work in this code?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning fetch API now.

I use arrow function it didn't work ,but use normal function it works.
Why this happened?

I also call the arrow function on Console of Chrome . It work fine....I don't get it
My understand is arrow function equal to normal function?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fetch Api</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="getText">Get Text</button>
    
<script>

        
    document.getElementById('getText').addEventListener
    ('click', getText);

    // function getText() {
    //     fetch('sample.txt')
    //     .then((res) => res.text())
    //     .then((data) => console.log(data))         
    // }

   const getText = () => {
        fetch('sample.txt')
        .then((res) => res.text())
        .then((data) => console.log(data))   
    } 


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put your [mcve] in the question _as text_, including the error message.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Answer (score -2):

You're attaching the `getText()` event listener *before* you define it.

Comment: It work!Thank you! But why normal function doesn't need to attach before event listener?

Comment: It's not just arrow functions that don't work this way, if you defined a function with `const foo = function() { }` order is also important.